# Return a value from a recursive function

Tags: php, recursion

I have a function that I can get all the correct values for with an echo, but when I cannot figure out how to get the whole array returned.  Could someone help me figure out to get the all of the child users?

```
    $useridarray[] = $userid;
    getchildren($useridarray, $useridarray);

    function getchildren($array, $totalarray)
    {
        foreach($array as $arr)
        {
            $db_name = "dbname";
            $connection = @mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error());
            $db = @mysql_select_db($db_name, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
            $sql = "
                    select *
                    from users
                    where creator = '$arr'
                    ";
            $result = @mysql_query($sql, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
            {
                $newchildren[] = $row['id'];
                $totalarray[] = $row['id'];
                //echo $row['id'] . ' ';
            }
            mysql_close();
            getchildren($newchildren, $totalarray);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just on a practical and performance note, I would create a function to create a connection and select the database, passing these details to your function. Will reduce the overhead of creating and closing connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [pass by reference<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php):

```
function getchildren($array, &$totalarray)
                             ^
```

Usage:

```
$useridarray[] = $userid;
getchildren($useridarray, $useridarray);
var_dump($useridarray); # your result
```

Answer (score 0):

You need add return before

```
    mysql_close();
return getchildren($newchildren, $totalarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with PHP syntax but you likely want to implement a "Stopping Criteria" to return you results. So in your instance it would seem like you would want something where getChildren returns the localResults + recursive getChildren results that are totaled incrementally as you go through your foreach loop.